# How to activate group chat in Skype 4.3 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, skype

I have installed skype 4.3 in Ubuntu 14.04.
Everything seems normal but group chat not working.
How to enable group chat skype 4.3?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official sources [here](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12387/why-can-t-i-use-group-chat), the cloud based group chat is not yet available on **Skype for Linux**. However you can still do a conference call by clicking on Options and selecting **Start Conference Call**.

Comment: is there any way to achieve it

Comment: No. Ubuntu cannot do anything about it. Alternatively, you can install Wine emulator and install Skype for Windows. If you don't know, wine is a Windows application emulator for Linux. You can install it by entering `sudo apt-get install wine` in Terminal.

Comment: screw Microsoft.

Comment: @OccamRazor's solution worked for me on Ubuntu 16. Not sure about 14

Answer (score 18):

If you actually mean group chat and not video calls, write

```
/msnp24
```

in any Skype chat window, and restart Skype. And all of your group chats from any other machines and chat history will become available.

INFO: **[here](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-group-chat-not-working-anymore/td-p/3987288)**

Comment: Working, It comes in the Recent

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! Note : However, in my case I needed to logout from Skype and login again. Just restarting Skype didn't work.